# Time and Date getHour(), getDay() etc... still work on Android 2.3 and 3.0?

Tags: android, date, time, deprecated

these methods are deprecated... but... still work on android 2.3 or 3.0 ?

i'm sure they work on 2.1, cause i tested it on my android phone, but works also in 2.3 or 3.0 ?

Comment: Android 3.0 doesn't exists yet. As for Android 2.3, why didn't you try on the emulator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those methods are not android-specific, but is in the core java class library and have been deprecated since JDK 1.1 from around 1997. So they remain until there is a non-compatible version of java released.

Answer (score 0):

To add a little, in the Java world, `@Deprecated` is here to indicate methods you **should** not use. They still work, for compatibility reasons, but you are advised not to used them. Moreover, as [fornwall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440881/time-and-date-gethour-getday-etc-still-work-on-android-2-3-and-3-0/4441296#4441296) said, these are old Java 1.1 methods, not Android-specific ones.